# Unable to insert values in database The resulting value is out of range for the DECIMAL / NUMERIC data type (3.1)

Tags: java, database, derby

When I run my code, It works even shows this error:

`java.sql.SQLDataException: The resulting value is out of range for the DECIMAL / NUMERIC data type (3.1).`

My Java file:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Aula4 {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            
            String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sistema_academico";
            
            String usuario = "app";
            String senha = "app";
            Connection conexao;
            Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
            conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, senha);
            int id_aluno;
            double nota;
            String nome = null;
            
            System.out.println("Welcome, type your id: ");
            id_aluno = ler.nextInt();
            
            System.out.println("Now, do you need to type your name: ");
            nome = ler.next();
            
            System.out.println("And finally, type your grade:  ");
            nota = ler.nextDouble();
            
            String SQL_Update = "UPDATE aluno set NOTA=? WHERE id_aluno=?";
            String sql = "insert into aluno " +
                  "(id_aluno,nome, nota) " +
                  "values (?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement stmt = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setInt(1, id_aluno);
            stmt.setString(2, nome);
            stmt.setDouble(3, nota);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            stmt.execute();
            stmt.close();
            System.out.println("Accomplished!!");
            
            stmt = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
            
            }
             catch (SQLException ex){
            System.out.println("Conection failed!"+ex);
        } 
    }
}
```

I can type all inputs, but in the end, the program displays the error above. I want to insert values into my database, just this error It's disturbing me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stmt.execute();` is too much, and indeed might have caused an "erroneous" error.
The last `stmt = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);` too.

The [MySQL reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html) might help. **DECIMAL(3, 1)** has range -9.9 .. 9.9.
This might a correct scale, otherwise you maybe intended **DECIMAL(5, 2)**.

`nota` might be checked.

As floating point (`double`) is imprecise, it might even be better to use `BigDecimal` (fixed point) on java side.

```
        System.out.println("And finally, type your grade:  ");
        BigDecimal bdnota = ler.nextBigDecimal();

        // Check input: scale and digits
        System.out.println("Scale: " + bdnota.scale());

        stmt.setBigDecimal(3, bdnota);
```